# How do I use line_profiler on a wrapped function?

Tags: python, wrapper, line-profiler

I've been trying to use `line_profiler` on a wrapped function. However, the wrapper function gets profiled instead of the wrapped function. The executable snippet below shows that I can see that my `@decorate` wrapper function gets profiled instead of my `d()` function.

Snippet: testy_profiler.py

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler

def a():
    print("a")

from functools import wraps
def decorate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("decorating")
        return r
    return wrapper

@decorate
def d():
    print("d")

def go():
    a()
    d()

lprofiler = LineProfiler()
lprofiler.add_function(a)
lprofiler.add_function(d)
lp_wrapper = lprofiler(go)
lp_wrapper()
lprofiler.print_stats()
```

Output:

```
$ python test_profiler.py
a
d
decorating
Timer unit: 1e-07 s

Total time: 1e-05 s
File: C:\Users\RENARDCH\Workspace\testy_profiler\test_profiler.py
Function: a at line 3

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     3                                           def a():
     4         1        100.0    100.0    100.0      print("a")

Total time: 4.4e-06 s
File: C:\Users\RENARDCH\Workspace\testy_profiler\test_profiler.py
Function: wrapper at line 8

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     8                                                  @wraps(func)
     9                                                  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    10         1         24.0     24.0     54.5                 r = func(*args, **kwargs)
    11         1         18.0     18.0     40.9                 print("decorating")
    12         1          2.0      2.0      4.5                 return r

Total time: 1.87e-05 s
File: C:\Users\RENARDCH\Workspace\testy_profiler\test_profiler.py
Function: go at line 19

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    19                                           def go():
    20         1        126.0    126.0     67.4      a()
    21         1         61.0     61.0     32.6      d()
```

This especially poses problem when two functions are wrapped with the same wrapper, since a global profiling will be generated for the wrapper, instead of a profiling for each functions individually.

`line_profiler` version is `3.4.0`

Comment: Based on the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/167), it seems like you could do `lprofiler.add_function(d.__wrapped__)`. Does that work?

Comment: Awesome! If you post as an answer i'll accept. I've always wondered, how do you find a issue that quickly? Google did not redirect me to any issue.

Comment: I started by searching on GitHub for add_function() inside the line-profiler repository, so I can look at how it's implemented. While searching, I noticed that they had a test which used `wraps()`. "Awesome," I thought, "they already have a test for wrapped functions which I can copy." I read the test, and it's just checking that a warning for using wrapped functions shows up correctly. The warning was probably added for a reason, so I search for the issue/PR which added it. I find that issue, which points me to `__wrapped__` as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/167), line profiler will not profile code inside a decorated function, and will instead profile the decorator. (This issue is a month old at time of writing, and may have changed by the time you read this answer.)

There is a workaround, however.

If you want to profile the function which the decorator calls, you can do this:

```py
lprofiler.add_function(d.__wrapped__)
```

Since you are using `functool.wraps()`, that sets the `__wrapped__` attribute to point to the original function. Many other Python decorators set `__wrapped__` too, though it is not a requirement. More information can about `__wrapped__` can be found [here](https://rmariano.eu/posts/wrapped-in-python-decorators/).

Answer (score 1):

A bypass is to make `d()` call a non-wrapped function that *actually* does the job, and profile this sub-function instead of `d()`.

```
[...]
@decorate
def d():
    effective_d()

def effective_d():
    print("d")

[...]
lprofiler.add_function(effective_d)
[...]
```